org.apache.http.wire display JWT token, how do I hide it?

Hi, When I run Karate parallel runner with log masking, I noticed that org.apache.http.wire still displays the token string whereas com.intuit.karate has hidden the token string ok.
Is there a way for me to configure the org.apache.http.wire to hide the sensitive information like JWT token in this case?

Yes you should be able to do this in the logback-test.xml file.
Details here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#logging
Looks like you don't have this in place at all.
If you have it in place, try adding this snippet:
<logger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>


Thank you,Should I put the logback-test.xml in here /src/test/java/logback-test.xml
Or  here
/logback-test.xml ?

@TonyThongsinthop src/test/java or src/test/resources depending on how you set up your project: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#classpath
